# console.log always printing same thing when code is different in Angular 1 app

Tags: javascript, angularjs, console.log

I am trying to complete the Angular 1.5 tutorial from this YouTube series: [Angular 1.5 tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=81hNHPEQPtk). Angular 1 because my work still uses it and I need to become better with it.

The problem is as follows: I created a blog-list.component.js and blog-list.module.js file along with an app.module.js file. I am writing a console.log() message in the component file that basically says `console.log("hello sir");`, but previously I had `console.log("hello");`. Now whenever I try to change the console.log message it just console logs hello, not the updated console message. I am not sure what I could have done wrong, but I can't seem to be able to find my mistake. Perhaps you might be able to see it? Here are the file contents:

blog-list.component.js:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('blogList').
  controller('BlogListController', function() {
    console.log("hello sir");
  });
```

blog-list.module.js:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('blogList', []);
```

app.module.js:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('try', ['blogList']);
```

index.html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app='try'>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Let's Build Angular!</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.5/angular.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script src="./js/app/app.module.js"></script>
    <script src="./js/app/app.config.js"></script>

    <script src="./js/app/blog-list/blog-list.module.js"></script>
    <script src="./js/app/blog-list/blog-list.component.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input type="text" ng-model='name'>
    <h2>This is going to be a working Angular Page for <span ng-if="name">{{ name }}</span><span ng-if="!name">WoRlD</span></h2>

    <div class='' ng-controller='BlogListController'>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

### I have a feeling that the mistake is something really stupid, but I just can't see it. The help is much appreciated!

Comment: Did you clear the web browser cache, your scripts might be cached and thus pulling up an old version.

Comment: And if not the above, then how are you serving this thing?

Comment: Yes, I have tried clearing the cache and I have also launched the app using incognito mode in Chrome. I am serving it using 'python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8080' on my Mac.

Comment: Do you have a build script that is run to generate the HTML file your browser sees? Maybe you need to run it again. It could be a command like `npm run build` or `npm run gulp build-dev` or `npm start`.

Comment: Isn't Angular run in the browser? I listed all my files above and I tried to restart the server already?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds more like cache issue rather than anything, 
Did you try to open chrome developer option and click the Network -> disable cache
then ctrl + f5

Comment: Yes, I have tried clearing the cache and I have also launched the app using incognito mode in Chrome. Same thing happens with Chrome and Safari